# Ideas to fill missing data

Tags: python, data-cleaning, missing-data

I have a column with precipitation data. 40% data is missing & I don't was to drop the empty cells.
As with any precipitation data, mean & median are far apart
Description of the data

```
count    7213.000000
mean       10.942007
std        29.808576
min         0.000000
25%         0.000000
50%         0.000000
75%         7.100000
max       461.000000
```

How should I fill the data?
Fill empty cells with mean? median? random values?
I am a beginner.

Comment: Is the goal to replace missing values with the "best guess"( i.e. mean or median)?  If the goal **not** have the missing values used in calculations by Pandas functions then replace them with np.nan.

Answer (score 0):

How about an arbitrary number that you know is not possible? -1 for instance

Comment: What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sample data, if you only want to replace the missing value with mean, mean, or max/min, it's not hard, I can provide you a simple code to do it.

Thanks
Leon